# Tabstrip like Flipboard app

Tags: android, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip, pagertabstrip

I'm trying to make a tabstrip, linked to a ViewPager, that has the same look and feel as in the Flipboard app.

[image: Flipboard App]

I tried different libs, and even decompiled their app, but I can't find how they did this.
So far, I managed to have a regular Material design tabs, like that, using default android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.
[image: Using default android.support.design.widget.TabLayout]

But the selection color is not animated, and the tabstrip doesn't scroll.

If it was for me, I would just go Material, but it's not my choice, I have to deal with what my boss tells me to do.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Did you find something? I am trying to do the same.

Comment: No, sorry. I'm using a regular TabLayout with Fixed layout. It's the best I could do.